# Using PyMix, saving m.em() 's final iteration to a vector or something

Tags: python, statistics, package, mixture-model

I'm using the pymix package to solve a mixture model.

```
        m = mixture.MixtureModel(3,[0.1,0.8,0.1], [n1,n2,n3])

        # Resolver el Mixture model

        m.EM(data,100,0.1)
```

I cant afterwards do a

```
        print m
```

and I can see the final means and std's for a mixture of 3 gaussians. The problem is that 
I want to access these means and std's to to some computations with them but have no idea
how to do so, m.EM() returns a tuple of posterior matrix and log-likelihood from the last iteration but apparently not these means and standard deviations, is there something im missing here? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing of PyMix, but `print m` calls `m.__str__()`, and [the source code](http://pymix.org/docu/mixture-pysrc.html#MixtureModel.__str__) is readily available for you to see where each value comes from.

Comment: Ok, so  I can do m.componentes[1] for example, which gives me normal:[-0.55332,1.21267] for example. But this is an instance of the class, I would like to make it an array or something so I can access the values, Each m.component[i] is of the form Normali:[meani,stdi]. Greetings.

Comment: @JEquihua You can dig deeper into that class. Perhaps there is a documented method for accessing the values. If not, turn to the source.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to extract the mean and stdev by:

```
x1 = str(m.components[index])
x2 = x1[26:-2].split(",")
mean, stdev = list(map(float,x2))
```

My x1 grabs the 'ProductDist: \n  Normal:  [mean, stdev]\n' which prints when you 'print m'. The x2 grabs the 'mean, stdev' into an array, and the last line maps the string versions of the mean and the stdev to floats.